# My fund was stuck at ParaSpace, multi signer A&B initiated the code on@safe, but C said they were doing sth else, can someone help me?

Tags: ether, contract-deployment, contract-debugging, gnosis-safe

It was a long story, i mistakenly sent 12eth to Para. https://etherscan.io/tx/0x72ef5f105ec1c40f917d92aa48caafe24448d9d8507c303ee9a66cbad2c0e983

but somehow para side set up this https://app.safe.global/home?safe=eth:0xe965198731CDdB2f06e91DD0CDff74b71e4b3714
that is the transaction address, can someone help me looking into these. Did multisigner AB really just adding code to rescue my fund and transfer into my original address, or they wanna do sth more than it.

Answer (score 0):

now you have to follow some step to receive your eth to your account this transaction start 96 days ago right

yes its take time but your stuck amount is high so you can do

Read this https://docs.alchemy.com/docs/multi-sig-contracts

step 1 : contact to ParaSpace through their official channel and explain your current sittuation, provide all valid detail like

transaction id, amount ,multi signer all address

para sapce help in this problem

i give some contact information of parax
please contact all the possible way

twitter :https://twitter.com/ParaX_ai

also contact to all team member who are work in parax
website : https://parax.ai/

if above step not useful then you have to contact blockchain expert they can help you